# Segmentation fault in C with file

Tags: c, fault

I have a segmentation fault in the moment of get the second file in the function imprimir, and i dont know whats happend, because he open and read the firts but not other file, is very confused for me, please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char nombre[40];
    int creditos;
    float nota;
} curso;

int conteo(FILE *_entrada);
void semestre(FILE *_entrada,curso *_materias,int *_cantidad,int *_ganadas,int *_perdidas,float *_promedio);
void imprimir(curso *_materias,int *_cantidad,int *_ganadas, int *_perdidas,float *_promedio);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ganadas=0;
    int perdidas=0;
    float promedio=0.0;
    int cantidad=0;
    char *archivoEntrada;
    curso *materias;
    printf("Archivo de entrada \n");
    scanf("%s",archivoEntrada);
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada=fopen(archivoEntrada,"r");
    if(entrada==NULL)
    {
        printf("No se logro abrir el archivo de entrada\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cantidad=conteo(entrada);
    printf("El numero de materias es: %d \n",cantidad);

    materias=(curso *)malloc(sizeof(curso)*cantidad);

    semestre(entrada,materias,&cantidad,&ganadas,&perdidas,&promedio);
    imprimir(materias,&cantidad,&ganadas,&perdidas,&promedio);
    free(materias);
}

int conteo(FILE *_entrada)
{
    int i=0;
    char auxiliar[40];
    while(!feof(_entrada))
    {
        fgets(auxiliar,40,_entrada);
        i++;
    }
    rewind(_entrada);
    return i/3;
}

void semestre(FILE *_entrada,curso *_materias,int *_cantidad,int *_ganadas,int *_perdidas,float *_promedio)
{
    int i=0;
    int sumaCreditos=0;
    float sumaNotas=0.0;
    while(i<*_cantidad)
    {
        fscanf(_entrada, "%s", _materias->nombre);
        fscanf(_entrada, "%d", &_materias->creditos);
        sumaCreditos=sumaCreditos+(_materias->creditos);
        fscanf(_entrada, "%f", &_materias->nota);
        if((_materias->nota)>3.0)
        {
            *_ganadas=(*_ganadas)+1;
        }
    }
}

void imprimir(curso *_materias,int *_cantidad,int *_ganadas, int *_perdidas,float *_promedio)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ganadas %d \n",*_ganadas);
    printf("perdidas %d \n",*_perdidas);
    printf("prom %f \n",*_promedio);
    char *archivoSalida;
    FILE *salida;
    printf("Archivo de salida \n");
    scanf("%s",archivoSalida);
    salida=fopen(archivoSalida,"w");
    if(salida==NULL)
    {
        printf("No se logro abrir el archivo de salida\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //Implementacion imprimir en archivo salida.txt
}
```

Comment: It looks like part of your code is missing. The braces aren't balanced, and I don't think you really meant to define the `imprimir()` function inside the `semestre()` function.

Comment: Don't do `fflush(stdin)`, it's undefined in the C specification.

Comment: [while (!feof(_entrada)) is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
char *archivoSalida;
```

and then

```
scanf("%s",archivoSalida);
```

The problem here is that the pointer `archivoSalida` doesn't actually point anywhere special. Uninitialized local variables (like `archivoSalida` is) have an *indeterminate* value. Using them without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*, a very common cause of crashes.

Instead you might want to use a fixed-size array:

```
char archivoSalida[256];
...
scanf("%255s",archivoSalida);
```

Comment: Same for `char *archivoEntrada;`